# How to check in JavaScript if object is in array with multiple objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

I have an array given with multiple objects as entries (collection) and I want to check if another source object is in those single entry objects. If so I want to return an array with all the objects that fulfill that condition. Here is the code with an example:

```
function whatIsInAName(collection, source) {
    var arr = [];
    var sourceEntries = Object.entries(source);
    for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; i < sourceEntries.length; i ++) {
            if((collection[i].hasOwnProperty(sourceEntries[j][0]))) {
                if(collection[i][sourceEntries[j][0]] == sourceEntries[j][1]) {
                    /*what happens here*/
                }
            }
        arr.push(collection[i]);
        }

    }
    return arr;
}

print(whatIsInAName([{ "a": 1, "b": 2 }, { "a": 1 }, { "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 2 }], { "a": 1, "b": 2 }));
```

Obviously I don't know what to put where it's written ("what happens here"). The problem is basically that the second for loop and both if conditions have to be `true` so the push command makes sense.

I appreciate any hint or help , thanks!

P.S. I know that this is probably not the most elegant way to solve it so happy about any other solutions as well.

Comment: Can you give a sample input and output? I think that would help someone figure out exactly what you need.

Comment: I mean depending how thorough you really want to be, you could just test if `JSON.stringify(item_in_array) == JSON.stringify(search_object)`

Comment: Of course, @ArnavAggarwal !
So basically what it is in the print statement is the input, output should be: 
`[{"a": 1, "b": 2}, {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}]` because those two objects contain both 'a' and 'b'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where the built-in [`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function comes in handy:

```js
function whatIsInAName(collection, source) {
  return collection.filter((obj) => {
    for (var prop in source) {
      if (source[prop] !== obj[prop]) {
        // The source property is not found in obj - no good!
        return false;
      }
      // The source property matches one of the obj's properties - keep going!
    }
    // Made it through the checks! You've got a match!
    return true;
  });
}

console.log(whatIsInAName([{
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2
}, {
  "a": 1
}, {
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2,
  "c": 2
}], {
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2
}));
```

Or, if you're inclined to use a library to do this, it can be done very simply with [Lodash](https://lodash.com/):

```js
var collection = [{ "a": 1, "b": 2 }, { "a": 1 }, { "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 2 }],
    source = { "a": 1, "b": 2 };

console.log(_.filter(collection, source));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, @j-titus Smooth and elegant way to solve it. Very much appreciated!